# Makefile 'ifeq'/'findstring' Seemingly Incorrect String Comparison Behavior

Tags: c, makefile

I have several makefile variables defined similar to this ...

```
BUILD_DIR = build

APP_SRCS =    \
  ./main.c    \
  ./module1.c \
  ./module2.c \
  etc.        \

APP_OBJS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, $(notdir $(APP_SRCS:.c=.o)))
```

... and a rule defined similar to this ...

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    echo "---"$@"---" "---"$(findstring $@, $(APP_OBJS))"---"
    ifeq ($(findstring $@, $(APP_OBJS)), $@)
        echo "---App---"
    else
        echo "---Lib---"
    endif
```

When this rule is executed, the `if` block is always executed.  For example, consider the following terminal output:

> ---build/main.o--- ---build/main.o---
>   ---App---
>
> ---build/lib1.o--- ------
>   ---App---

In both cases, `findstring` works correctly.  The problem I'm having is that whether the substring is found in the string or not, that is, `$@` is found in `$(APP_OBJS)` or not, the `if` block is always taken.  I want to use such a construct to compile application and library source files with different warning flags to mute all library warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue but I was trying to use ifeq to reference $(MAKEFLAGS) in a "functional context" rather than a "rule context". I think its worth noting here that $(if ...) is the feature to use in functional context, for example the construct on page 83:

```
ifneq (,$(findstring t,$(MAKEFLAGS))
   touch archive.a ranlib -t    
   archive.a 
else 
   ranlib archive.a 
endif
```

Only works in a rule, and not outside of a rule. But

```
FOO=$(if $(findstring t,$(MAKEFLAGS)), present, notpresent)
```

works outside of rule context.

Answer (score 3):

This statement:

```
ifeq ($(findstring $@, $(APP_OBJS)), $@)
```

is a *Make* conditional, and Make will evaluate before executing any rule, and therefore before the automatic variable `$@` has a value. So Make expands "$@" to nothing:

```
ifeq ($(findstring , $(APP_OBJS)),)
```

the `findstring` returns the empty list since it didn't find a match:

```
ifeq (,)
```

and the conditional evaluates as true.

You already have one solution: use a *shell* conditional. Or you could use a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
$(APP_OBJS): $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    echo "---"$@"---" "---"$@"---"
    echo "---App---"

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    echo "---"$@"---" "---""---"
    echo "---Lib---"
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works as expected:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    if test $(findstring $@, $(APP_OBJS)); then \
        echo "---App---"; \
    else \
        echo "---Lib---"; \
    fi;
```